# WordPress custom shortcode breaks saving process (post.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm experiencing a strange issue with shortcodes in WordPress. When I save the page while the shortcode is added, it redirects me to `wp-admin/post.php` and shows me a white page with the results of the shortcode in html format (see screenshot 1).  Luckily, all the editing is saved.

The funny thing is that I've done this a dozen times with the exact same method. But for a short while now it doesn't work anymore.

I do hope you see the issue and know what we can do to fix it.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfkT1.png)

The PHP code that I'm using is added to the `functions.php`

The shortcode that I'm using is `[showblog cat="planning" number=4]`

```
function showblog_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'number'    => '-1',
        'cat'       => '',
    ], $atts, 'showblog' );

    $numberposts = $atts['number'];
    $categorie = $atts['cat'];

    //args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => $numberposts,
        'order'             => 'ASC',
    );

    if($categorie != ""){
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'posts_per_page'    => $numberposts,
            'category_name'     => $categorie,
            'order'             => 'ASC',
        );
    }

    // The Query
    $the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul class="blog-list clearfix">';
        while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query2->the_post();

            echo '<li class="blog-block">';
            echo '  <div class="blog-info">';
            echo '    <h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4>';
            echo '    <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
            echo '    <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" class="blog-button">Read full post</a>';
            echo '  </div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'showblog', 'showblog_func' );
```

Comment: Shortcode is working fine in page/post.

Comment: Hi Mukesh,

Thank you for your reply. The shortcode is indeed working fine.

But when I add the shortcode to a page and click 'update'. It redirects me to post.php and shows the shortcodes' value in HTML format (see screenshot 1).

Comment: Then any code from theme or plugin is generating error when you try to save post so disable plugin one by one and check if it resolve your issue

Answer (score 3):

It's solved by adding `ob_start();` right after the first `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same and found the way to fix
just add `ob_start();` before html start and `ob_get_clean();` to end like this

```
function form_creation(){
  ob_start(); 
?>
    <form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Message:    <textarea name="message"> Enter text here...</textarea>
    </form>
<?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('test', 'form_creation');
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

This is not intended, is very broken, and happens because the WordPress REST API endpoint that gives content to the editor fires the `the_content` hook, when it should not.

Use `is_admin()` to prevent processing on admin pages.

### More Details

There's an [old issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/18988) on this subject. Here's an excerpt:

> Loading in the rendered post content has some strange side effects and can cause unintended behavior. As an example, any shortcodes or dynamic blocks are fully rendered in this request. This means that any API requests or heavy computations that either undertake are performed on the server (affecting TTFB) and then again in `ServerSideRender` in the case of dynamic blocks. Additionally, it means that the blob sent to the client is significantly larger, but that's a much smaller issue.

As you can see, this is a much bigger issue that has broader consequences, including unnecessary computational and network activity. Judging by the rest of the issue, effort is being made. At this time, it is unclear when this will be resolved by the core.

### Workaround

As is mentioned in [a comment](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/18394#issuecomment-552593461), it's possible to go around this by conditionally preventing processing/rendering when on admin pages. You can use the [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) function for this.

---

### Acknowledgement

I would like to point out that other solutions given here related to returning output rather than `echo`ing it are *wrong* in that this has nothing to do with the problem experienced by the OP, and do not prevent the shortcode from being rendered. They only prevent the shortode from producing output.

That said, you absolutely should return the output string, instead of `echo`ing it, as per [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) documentation:

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score -1):

You can't echo the shortcode HTML.

You need to bind HTML in variable and then return this HTML from shortcode..

Please check the code below

```
function _login_popup() {

    $html = '<form id="user-login-form" method="post" action="#" class="js-form-redirect js-form-action" novalidate="">
               <div class="floating-label form-group">
                  <input id="useremail" name="user_name" required="" value="" type="email">
                  <label for="useremail">Email</label>
               </div>
               <div class="floating-label form-group">
                  <input id="userpassword" name="password" required="" value="" type="password">
                  <label for="userpassword">Password</label>
               </div>
               <div class="o-form__buttons text-right --small-center">
                  <button type="submit" id="submit_login" class="a-button-form --save a-no-before" value="edit">Sign in</button>
               </div>
      </form>';

return $html;
}
add_shortcode('yg-login-popup', '_login_popup');
```